# butterfly flying animation using core animation in Iphone

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I am trying to do a  butterfly flapping its wings and fly across the screen in random continuously motion in core animation? How would that be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CAKeyframeAnimation documentation :
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

and CAAnimationGroup : http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimationGroup_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Using the **position**, and **transform** keyPath, it shouldn't be hard to achieve this, after it just a matter of design.